# Read .xlsx using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fill

I am trying to read the `.xlsx` file as dataframe. but getting Fill() takes no arguments as an error. I'm using google colab
first

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel('/content/Task_IOT.xlsx')
```

|Second

```
! pip install openpyxl
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel("/content/Task_IOT.xlsx", None)
```

and Third

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'Task_IOT.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df
```

And always got `TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5D5a.jpg)

Comment: How many worksheet does your excel have ?

Comment: test number 4:
`df = pd.read_excel('Task_IOT.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")`

Comment: @Echo two: query and results. I want the second one, with the results
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak7dTS2-W6WZdax5-K3mN2ktC0I?e=E74Fj1

Comment: pd. read_excel(r'Task_IOT.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Results')

Comment: Any reason to use `openpyxl` package instead of letting pandas to chose it? I think it is discountinued